# Didática simples de Ponteiros

Tags: c, ponteiro

Sou um programador esporádico, e sempre que preciso usar ponteiros, percebi que já esqueci como se usa, e tenho que ralar pra aprender tudo de novo.

Alguém tem alguma didática simples para lembrar o conceito de ponteiros, e que seja fácil de guardar? Eu sempre aprendo, já aprendi umas 8 vezes, mas sempre esqueço também!

Grato.

Comment: Boa tarde, pode seguir este tutorial daqui da USP...é bastante interessante e possui exemplos para tudo que eles explicam. Bom proveito. http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/pont.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Uma maneira de se ver ponteiros é fazendo uma analogia com nomes e endereços. Digamos que Alice mora no número 42 da rua X, Bob mora no número 43 e Charlie no 44. Se você só conhece a Alice, mas não sabe nem se interessa por onde ela mora, você pode interagir com ela e somente ela.

```
int array[3] = {10, 20, 30};
int x = array[0]; // Você conhece o valor 10, mas não sabe em que posição de memoria ele está
int y = x + x;    // Você pode fazer operações com essa valor

array[0] = 40;   // Se o valor do array mudar
printf("%d", x); // x continua sendo 10

x = 50;
printf("%d", array[0]); // E vice-versa (40)
```

Por outro lado, se tudo o que você sabe é onde Alice mora, então você tem que ir lá para encontrar com ela. Se ela se mudar, você vai encontrar outra pessoa em seu lugar.

```
int array[3] = {10, 20, 30};
int *x = &array[0]; // Dessa vez você salvou a posição de memória em que o valor 10 está
                    // &v significa "o endereço de v"; x não contém 10, mas o endereço do 10
int y = *x + *x;    // Se o 10 ainda estiver lá, você pode fazer operações com ele
                    // *x significa "o valor no endereço x"; ou seja, 10

array[0] = 40;    // Se o valor do array mudar
printf("%d", *x); // *x passa a ser 40
                  // x não mudou, continua sendo o mesmo endereço; o ocupante do endereço é que mudou
```

Além disso, se você tem o endereço de Alice, você pode visitar os seus vizinhos.

```
int array[3] = { 10, 20, 30 };
int *x = &array[0]; // x guarda o endereço do primeiro valor do array (10)

printf("%d", *x); // 10

x++;              // Ao incrementar o x, ele passa a guardar o endereço do valor seguinte
printf("%d", *x); // 20

x++;
printf("%d", *x); // 30
```

Mas cuidado! Se você se afastar demais da rua conhecida, você pode acabar em qualquer lugar; provavelmente um lugar perigoso... :P

```
x++;              // O 30 está numa posição de memória qualquer; na posição seguinte, tem alguma
                  // coisa, mas você não sabe o que é.
printf("%d", *x); // Um valor inesperado, ou segmentation fault
```

Até agora, só dei exemplos que observavam "o valor que está no endereço `x`". Mas é bom frisar que `x` é uma variável como qualquer outra: ela tem um valor, e existe em uma posição de memória.

```
int array[3] = {10, 20, 30};
int *x = &array[0];

printf("%d", x); // Aqui ele vai imprimir o endereço em memória do 10;
                 // pode ser qualquer coisa, inclusive mudar de uma invocação pra outra

int **z = &x; // Agora z tem a posição de memória onde está x
*z++;         // Se ele incrementar o valor que está lá
printf("%d", x); // x passa a ser o endereço em memória do 20
printf("%d", *x); // 20
```

**Adendo:** Como demonstrado na [resposta do Lucas Virgili](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/26642/215), uma das utilidades dos ponteiros (além da de percorrer arrays, matrizes, etc, e de se criar dados dinamicamente via `malloc` etc) é permitir que uma função altere valores que só existem fora dessa função. Mas é preciso ter cuidado, pois às vezes a posição de memória que antes guardava alguma coisa útil agora já foi "reciclada" pra outra coisa qualquer:

```
int *foo() {
    int x = 42;  // O valor 42
    int *y = &x; // O endereço de memória onde 42 está
    return y;
}

...

int *z = foo();   // O endereço de memória onde o 42 estaVA
bar();
printf("%d", *z); // (foo já terminou, então suas variáveis locais não estão necessariamente na mesma
                  //  posição de memória - ou sequer ainda existem [garantidamente])
```

Via de regra, passar ponteiros (ou endereços) para funções que você está chamando é OK, retornar ponteiros ou salvá-los pro futuro, só se você souber bem o que está fazendo.

Comment: Uma coisa que pode parecer confusa (pelo menos pra mim que nunca uso C): `int *x = &array[0];` é o mesmo que `int *x; x = &array[0];`, e **não** `int *x; *x = &array[0];`. Certo?

Comment: @bfavaretto Certo. Toda vez que se declara e atribui uma variável ao mesmo tempo, se está atribuindo o valor dela, e nada mais. Enxergue `int *x` como `(int *)x` - ou `T x`. `T x = y;` => `T x; x = y;`. O fato de `T == (int *)` não muda isso. Já a operação de **dereferência** (*dereferencing*) - com ou sem atribuição - deve ser vista como algo à parte. Enxergue `*x` como `*(x)` - ou `op(x)`. P.S. Justamente pra evitar esse tipo de confusão, muita gente prefere usar `int* x` em vez de `int *x`. Eu também faria assim se ainda mexesse com C. Amanhã atualizo a resposta com esses detalhes.

Comment: Realmente me faltava essa peça. Também acho `int* x` bem mais claro.

Answer (score 14):

De fato, como o @Dante disse, o tutorial do Feofiloff e muito bom, mas vou tentar a minha propria explicacao.

Suponha que voce tenha uma memoria com 5 posicoes. Cada posicao tem um endereco, indo de 0 a 4:

```
Endereco         0            1           2           3           4
           +------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
           |            |           |            |           |           |
           |            |           |            |           |           |
Valor      |    17      |     -12   |    99999   |   0       |   3.14    |
           |            |           |            |           |           |
           |            |           |            |           |           |
           +------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Como voce pode ver, cada endereco tem um **valor** associado. Quando nos declaramos uma variavel, o que nos estamos fazendo e dando um *nome* para alguma dessas posicoes, certo? Por exemplo:

```
int x; // O compilador vai fazer sua magica e alguma posicao da memoria vai
       // receber o nome x
```

Digamos que `x` tenha sido a posicao de endereco 1:

```
Endereco         0            1           2           3           4
           +------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
           |            |           |            |           |           |
           |            |           |            |           |           |
Valor      |    17      |     -12   |    99999   |   0       |   3.14    |
           |            |           |            |           |           |
           |            |           |            |           |           |
           +------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
                              /                                   
                             /                                    
                            /                                    
                           x
```

E nos executemos esse comando:

```
x = 123; // agora essa posicao vai ter seu valor alterado para 123.
```

Nos vamos ficar com:

```
Endereco         0            1           2           3           4
           +------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
           |            |           |            |           |           |
           |            |           |            |           |           |
Valor      |    17      |     123   |    99999   |   0       |   3.14    |
           |            |           |            |           |           |
           |            |           |            |           |           |
           +------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
                              /                                   
                             /                                    
                            /                                    
                           x
```

Correto? Agora, suponha que nos, ao inves de querer nos referir ao **valor** de `x`, nos queiramos saber *onde* `x` esta na memoria, por exemplo, para alterarmos o valor dele em outra funcao. Nos podemos fazer isso usando o operador `&`:

```
int endereco = &x; // endereco vai valer 1, o endereco da variavel x
```

Como eu disse, nos podemos querer isso para alterar o **valor** de `x` em outra funcao, ja que em C, passagem de parametros e feita por valor (ou seja, o valor da variavel e copiado para o parametro, nao a 'variavel' em si). Logo, se nos quisermos fazer uma funcao "incrememento", que incremente o seu parametro em 1, nos podemos fazer algo como:

```
void incremento(int *a) {
    *a = *a + 1;
}
```

O que isso quer dizer? A funcao `incremento` nao recebe mais um valor inteiro, ela recebe um ponteiro para uma posicao na memoria. Quando fazemos, entao, `*a = *a + 1;`, a funcao sabe exatamente o endereco na memoria do parametro dela, e o `*a` indica o valor que esta naquele endereco.

Logo, se nos fizermos a seguinte chamada da funcao incremento:

```
incremento(&x); // Passamos para incremento o endereco de X
```

O que acontece na memoria e algo como:

```
                                  /------------
                                 /             \
                                /               \
Endereco         0            1           2      \    3           4
           +------------+-----------+------------+\----------+-----------+
           |            |           |            | \         |           |
           |            |           |            |  \        |           |
Valor      |    17      |     124   |    99999   |   1       |   3.14    |
           |            |           |            |     \     |           |
           |            |           |            |      \    |           |
           +------------+-----------+------------+-------\---+-----------+
                              /                           \
                             /                             \
                            /                              *a
                           x
```

Ou seja, `*a` esta apontando diretamente para o valor de que esta no endereco de memoria 1, ou seja, `x`.

Esse e o uso mais fundamental de ponteiros em C. Melhor entender o basico antes do resto :P

Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Muito boa a resposta, mas o finalzinho ficou um pouco confuso: "esta apontando diretamente para o valor de x". Ele não aponta pra um valor, mesmo porque se o valor mudar ele vai continuar apontando pro mesmo endereço (que vai ter um valor diferente). Posso dar uma sugestão? Escolha um dos outros quadrinhos e coloque o valor `1` nele, associando ele ao `*a` (tal como 123 associa ao `x`). Depois puxe uma seta desse `1` até o endereço `1`, onde está o `123`. Mostrando que o `*a` guarda o endereço onde está o `x`.

Comment: De fato :) Vou fazer isso!

Answer (score 10):

A memória é como um grande e espaçoso hotel. Ele tem muitos quatros, todos numerados, e em cada um desses pode haver alguém.

[image: hotel]

Ter um quarto é como ter uma variável. Ela é sua e ninguém mais pode usar. Você é livre para fechar sua conta e ir embora quando bem entender. Mas o ponteiro é um pouco diferente de ter um quarto. Um ponteiro é uma chave. Se você guardar a chave de um quarto pode ir ver ele quando quiser. Pode também ver o número do quarto que está na sua chave e conseguir uma chave para os quartos ao lado, no mesmo corredor. Desse jeito você pode entrar no quarto, mexer em algo e sair sem o dono notar o que aconteceu.

```
int quarto = 25;
int* chave = &quarto;
*chave = 17;

printf("%d", quarto); // Eeei! Mexeram no meu quarto
```

Ou seu quarto é parte de um corredor:

```
int corredor[] = {10, 20, 30};
int* chave2 = &corredor[1];
*chave2 = corredor[0];

printf("%d", corredor[1]); // Ops, meu vinte sumiu
```

Você pode chegar em outro quarto do corredor:

```
int corredor[] = {10, 20, 30};
int* chave2 = &corredor[1];
int* chave3 = chave2 + 1;
*chave3 = corredor[0];


printf("%d", corredor[2]); // Mas eu nem dei a chave desse quarto!
```

Muito legal! Posso entrar no quarto de todo mundo! Mas onde está o perigo? Bom... Imagine que você alugou um quarto, pegou uma chave para ele, fez uma cópia dela e depois devolveu o quarto.

```
int* evil() {
    int quarto = 16;
    int* chave = &quarto;
    return chave;
}
```

O grande problema é que quando você voltar para ver o que tem dentro desse quarto, ele pode estar exatamente do jeito que você deixou. Pode ter ainda um 16 lá. Ou então pode ser que outra pessoa tenha alugado o mesmo quarto! E você vai encontrar coisas dessa outra pessoa lá. Talvez um seja feio -23587936. Quem sabe?

Mas veja só, se eu posso obter chaves para qualquer quarto a partir de uma chave que eu tenho, será que eu posso criar chaves para entrar onde eu bem entender?

```
int* chaveMestra = 5678; // Pronto, tenho a chave para o quarto 5678. Não sei o que tem lá.

int outroQuarto = *chaveMestra; // oops!
```

E se eu for entrar lá e tentar ver o quarto? Bem problemático. Pode ser que esse quarto nem exista. Pode ser de uma parte do hotel que existia a um tempo atrás mas foi demolida por que ninguém morava lá. Ou pior ainda, pode ser um quarto protegido. Sim! O gerente do hotel, o seu sistema operacional, tem o poder de te proibir de acessar alguns quartos. Ou ele pode até te deixar acessar, mas vai ficar de olho para você não mudar nada lá. Lembre-se, se você violar as regras do hotel será despejado sem direito a reclamações! Um belo segmentation fault.

Comment: Gostei da metáfora, só espero que minha memória seja menos bizarra que esse hotel da foto!

Answer (score 6):

Didática simples, certo? Então nada como um exemplo curto acompanhado de uma imagem. :)

### Ilustração

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Código

```c
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    /*** DECLARAÇÃO ***/
    int *i;
    int j;
    char c;
    char *s;

    /*** ATRIBUIÇÃO ***/
    i = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *i = 2;
    j = 42;
    s = "ola!";
    c = s[2];

    /*** APRESENTAÇÃO ***/

    printf("Endereco de i: 0x%x\n", &i);
    printf("Valor de i = 0x%x\n", i);
    printf("Valor apontado por i = %d\n", *i);
    printf("Endereco do valor apontado por i = 0x%x\n", &(*i));

    printf("Endereco de j: 0x%x\n", &j);
    printf("Valor de j: %d\n", j);
    // Valor apontado por j (e seu endereço) não faz sentido porque j não foi declarado como ponteiro
    // (gera erro "illegal indirection")

    printf("Endereco de s: 0x%x\n", &s);
    printf("Valor de s: 0x%x (%s)\n", s, s);
    printf("Valor apontado por s: %c\n", *s);
    printf("Endereco do valor apontado por s: 0x%x\n", &(*s));
    printf("Endereços de s[0], s[1], s[2] e s[3]: 0x%x, 0x%x, 0x%x e 0x%x\n", &(s[0]), &(s[1]), &(s[2]), &(s[3]));

    printf("Endereco de c: 0x%x\n", &c);
    printf("Valor de c = %c\n", c);
    // Mesmo comentário para o valor apontado por j, já que c também não foi declarado como um ponteiro

    /*** ENCERRAMENTO ***/
    free(i); // libera memória da única variável alocada dinamicamente

    return 0;
}
```

### Resultado (de exemplo)

```
Endereco de i: 0x95fef8
Valor de i = 0xad44d8
Valor apontado por i = 2
Endereco do valor apontado por i = 0xad44d8
Endereco de j: 0x95feec
Valor de j: 42
Endereco de s: 0x95fed4
Valor de s: 0x10cd08 (ola!)
Valor apontado por s: o
Endereco do valor apontado por s: 0x10cd08
Endereþos de s[0], s[1], s[2] e s[3]: 0x10cd08, 0x10cd09, 0x10cd0a e 0x10cd0b
Endereco de c: 0x95fee3
Valor de c = a
```