# Função com passagem por referência

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, referência

Estou tentando fazer uma função simples que conta diamantes, cada diamantes é dado por um par de '<' e '>'. Porém estou tentando fazer com ponteiros, mas não está me dando o resultado correto. Segui o ["Didática simples para ponteiros"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26633/did%C3%A1tica-simples-de-ponteiros), e de acordo com ele creio que estou fazendo corretamente. Onde está meu erro? Ao invés de mostrar o resultado, o número de diamantes, ele imprime sempre o mesmo endereço de memória.

Seguem as funções relevantes:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int casos; // número de casos de teste
    int n;
    int *diamantes; // aponta para número de diamantes
    char vetor[1000]; //variável para armazenar a entrada

    scanf("%d", &casos);

    for (n = 0; n < casos; n++) {
        limparBuffer();
        ler(vetor);
        contador(vetor, diamantes);
        printf("%d\n", diamantes);
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int contador(char vetor[], int *d) {
    int i, contEsq = 0, contDir = 0;
    int n = 1;
    for (i = 0; vetor[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (vetor[i] == '<')
            contEsq++;
        else if (vetor[i] == '>')
            contDir++;
    }


    if (contEsq > contDir)
        d = &contDir;
    else
        d = &contEsq;

}
```

Comment: Eu pergunto qual é o problema? Alguma coisa dá para perceber fácil mas seria melhor você dizer o que está ocorrendo com seu código que não deveria. Tem coisa que eu não sei ao certo se está errado porque pode ser que você queria o que está acontecendo. Quando ao ponteiro aconselho fortemente evitá-lo. Mesmo que seja só um exemplo, acho que não faz sentido complicar um programa para fazer algo desnecessário. Se quer usar o ponteiro, arrume algo que precise de um ponteiro.

Comment: Pergunta editada, concordo que poderia tornar tudo mais fácil usando apenas retornos, mas a intenção não é apenas entender, mas sim dominar este conteúdo. Por isso estou aplicando nas mais diversas tarefas onde ele não seria necessário, ou mesmo há maneiras de fazer a mesma coisa com mais facilidade. Grato pela dica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dominar o conteúdo é justamente nunca fazer algo onde não precisa. Fazer onde não precisa é aprender errado.

E de fato não faz o menor sentido fazer o que está fazendo. Eu posso responder para você o seguinte: não faça isto, tem um erro básico de entendimento de escopo de variável. Você está apontando para uma das duas variáveis criadas em `contador` e depois fora desta função vai tentar acessar esse endereço quando ele não deveria estar mais disponível.

Então qual é a solução para isto? Ela é muito simples, retorne o valor como qualquer código plausível faz. Tentar fazer coisa errada, vai dar resultado errado.

E pior, tem um outro problema. Ainda bem. Porque se não tivesse, iria funcionar por coincidência e você iria achar que estava fazendo certo.

Quando você faz `d = &contDir` está dizendo "pegue o endereço da variável `contDir` e jogue em `d`". Que depois será acessado fora da função por `diamantes` e imprimi-la. Ou seja, está mandando imprimir o endereço. E esse endereço não deve ser acessado de forma alguma, porque ele poderá não ter mais o que você você espera.

Então uma solução possível é tirar o operador de `d = contDir`. O que está tecnicamente errado e alguns compiladores podem sinalizar problema.

Outra forma é acessar `diamantes` derreferenciando: `printf("%d\n", diamantes);`. Mas continuará cometendo um erro em fazer isto por causa do escopo.

Provavelmente cometeu esse erro porque está querendo usar algo à qualquer custo. As coisas não funcionam assim.

Ainda há a solução: `*d = contDir;`. A mais correta mas totalmente desnecessária.

Tire esse parâmetro `d` e faça um `return` que você deveria fazer mesmo já que declarou o tipo desta função como `int`.

Não defina uma solução e procure um problema onde ela se encaixa. Isto não ensina ninguém. Se você insistir que está aprendendo algo fazendo isto não vou dizer como isto é chamado porque algumas pessoas considerariam agressivo. Vou dizer apenas que é teimosia.

Eu não sei se este é o único problema porque o código atual não é compilável, faltam partes.

Comment: Entendi os erros, e principalmente o mais grave e que torna o código inviável(erro de escopo), e agora sei por que não fazer o que estou fazendo é desnecessário e incorreto. Não tiro o seu direito de pensar que isso é burrice, e sua resposta me mostrou por que realmente seria. Grato.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro, a solução para o seu problema:

1a) troque a declaração `int *diamantes` por `int diamantes`

1b) Ou então, faça `int *diamantes = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int))`

2) Se você fez 1a, troque `contador(vetor, diamantes)` por `contador(vetor, &diamantes)`. Se você fez 1b, troque `printf("%d\n", diamantes)` por `printf("%d\n", *diamantes)`

3) troque `d = &contDir` e `d = &contEsq` por `*d = contDir` e `*d = contDir`

4) Se você fez 1b, então antes do `return (EXIT_SUCCESS)` faça `free(diamantes)`

Agora, a explicação:

**Não existe passagem por referência em C. Apenas, e exclusivamente, passagem por valor**. Acontece que, quando você passa um pointeiro, o **valor** passado é um endereço de memória. Com ele, você consegue acessar o conteúdo desse endereço de memória usando o operador * e alterá-lo.

O que você estava fazendo ao escrever `d = &contDir` era alterar o **valor** passado e não o **conteúdo**. Portanto, quando a função retornava, nada havia mudado e o seu printf estava imprimindo um valor arbitrário de endereço porque você não tinha inicializado o ponteiro.

Comment: O problema foi resolvido seguindo as dicas da primeira solução, porém achei a explicação satisfatória também, grato.

Answer (score 0):

Mude o código para:

```
if (contEsq > contDir)
    d* = contDir;
else
    d* = contEsq;
```

e me diga se funcionou.

Comment: Não funcionou ...

Comment: o que aconteceu desta vez ?

Comment: como o bigown falou a cima, como a função foi utilizada e no main ela está "perdida". Pelo menos isso o que eu entendi ...

Comment: C pode colocar o resto de código e dados de teste no pastebin pra eu compilar aqui ?

Comment: Claro, aqui o link do antigo(http://pastebin.com/JY9bKx8m), e aqui o do novo e funcionando(http://pastebin.com/E2Y6jpjb)