# Malloc reservando memória indevidamente?

Tags: c, ponteiro, alocação

Estou estudando alocação dinâmica de memória e me deparei com um erro que aparentemente o compilador não está alertando. O código é bem simples:

```
int *ptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
ptr[0] = 5;
ptr[1] = 10;
free(p);
```

Este código funciona normalmente, porém ele não está alocando memória indevidamente? Veja que o ponteiro `ptr` no índice `[1]` não existe, porém consegue atribuir um valor à ele. Com um `printf` os valores também são apresentados corretamente. O que há de incomum nesse código?

Comment: O facto de não dar erro é apenas azar. Não dar erro leva-te a pensar que "funciona". **Mas não funciona.** O que está a acontecer é o famoso [*Comportamento não definido*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamento_indefinido): tudo pode acontecer. O programa pode funcionar como se estivesse bem escrito, pode crashar imediatamente, pode crashar quando o chefe está a ver, pode pintar o tecto de amarelo, ..., ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "O que há de incomum nesse código?"

Nada de incomum, mas muito de errado. Aritmética de ponteiros é um recurso amplamente usado em linguagem C quando se deseja manipular *diretamente* o conteúdo na memória. Então, não é mesmo algo incomum em C. Porém, o programador precisa entender muito bem o uso de ponteiros e saber o que está fazendo para evitar erros (algumas vezes gravíssimos). Tanto pra aprender como para eventualmente descobrir e corrigir erros, o depurador é o seu melhor amigo.

Usando o depurador do Visual Studio 2012, faço a seguir uma análise linha a linha do seu código.

---

**1. Primeiro passo**

```
int *ptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

O que essa primeira linha faz é simplesmente alocar uma área de memória de tamanho fixo, definido por `sizeof(int)`, e armazenar esse endereço na variável `ptr`. Já há ai algumas considerações importantes. Primeiramente, o tamanho alocado vai depender da plataforma/sistema operacional em uso *e também* da configuração utilizada no compilador. Em um sistema de 32 bits, o inteiro usa 4 bytes para armazenamento (isto é, números representados em binário com até 32 bits), em um sistema de 64 bits usa 8 bytes, e por ai vai. Por isso que a plataforma define [o maior número inteiro que pode ser *endereçado*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inteiro_%28ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29#Exemplos_comuns) (para a contagem de handles de arquivos, por exemplo). Além disso, o compilador pode ser configurado para gerar código para uma plataforma específica. No meu exemplo, estou usando o Visual Studio 2012 em uma máquina Windows de 64 bits, mas compilando meu código intencionalmente para 32 bits. Por isso, o resultado de `sizeof(int)` *no meu exemplo* via ser igual a `4`.

Além disso, a função `malloc` aloca uma área de memória com o tamanho dado (em bytes) e retorna *um endereço* para o primeiro byte daquela área na memória. Esse endereço é, naturalmente, *endereçado* (redundância intencional aqui) usando números inteiros da plataforma (e é por isso que uma máquina de 64 bits pode ter mais memória, já que seu inteiro é maior e pode alcançar endereços mais longos). Em outras palavras, não importa se o seu ponteiro é um `char*` um `struct longa_estrutura*` ou `odiabo*`, seu endereço vai ser um número inteiro, geralmente representado em hexadecimal no formato `0x000A1F23`. Se tiver dúvidas sobre o uso de ponteiros, esta [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26633/did%C3%A1tica-simples-de-ponteiros) deve ser de alguma ajuda.

Assim, ao executar essa linha o que você tem (considerando que no meu exemplo estou executando um programa compilado para 32 bits) é uma área de memória de 4 bytes alocada em algum lugar, cujo endereço inicial é armazenado na variável `ptr` (no exemplo, o endereço `0x00773fe0`):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Note como os quatro primeiros bytes a partir da posição inicial contém
>   o valor `cd`. Isto se deve ao fato de eu ter executado em modo
>   *debug*, e por isso o compilador da Microsoft inicializa as áreas de memória com valores padronizados. Isto não acontece nesse compilador
>   se o programa for executado em modo *release* (por motivos de
>   desempenho), e assim poderia ter ali qualquer lixo decorrente de
>   execuções anteriores de outros programas.

**2. Segundo passo**

```
ptr[0] = 5;
```

Nesta linha ocorre a primeira ação de "aritmética" de ponteiros. Chama-se assim porque, na linguagem C, acessar `ptr[0]` é equivalente a acessar `ptr+0`.

> Você até pode ter outra variável que aponta para qualquer "posição" na
>   memória a partir do ponteiro inicial, por exemplo `int *ptr3 = ptr+3`
>   vai "apontar" para a posição em `ptr[3]` (ou seja, no último byte da memória alocada).

E o que você está fazendo é modificando o valor daquela área de memória, **a partir do endereço inicial apontado**, colocando ali o valor inteiro `5` (`101` em binário, ou `05` em hexadecimal). Por isso o seu resultado em memória é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note como os quatro primeiros bytes foram alterados (o Visual Studio é bomzinho e indica isso com a cor vermelha).

**3. Terceiro passo**

```
ptr[1] = 10;
```

Aqui novamente há uma aritmética de ponteiros (equivalente a `ptr+1`). Mas há uma questão importantíssima. Como o ponteiro foi declarado como um ponteiro para um tipo inteiro (de 4 bytes no meu exemplo), a soma efetuada pelo compilador não é equivalente a 1 byte, mas sim a 4 bytes! Então, na prática, essa aritmética `ptr+1` vai equivaler, em termos de memória, a `ptr+4` bytes. E, por isso, o seu resultado em memória será o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**E é ai que está o erro**. Com essa manipulação, você está "invadindo" uma área de memória que não foi alocada para o seu programa (isto é, escrevendo além do espaço que foi de fato reservado). E dai podem ocorrer inúmeros cenários: você pode invadir uma área que não está sendo usada, e não acontecer nada; você pode invadir uma área de memória de outro programa, o que vai ser impedido pelo sistema operacional causando um erro no seu programa; você pode alterar o valor de uma variável qualquer de outra parte do seu próprio programa, causando resultados bizarros dos mais diversos, etc.

**4. Exemplo adicional**

Uma aritmética de ponteiros que seria mais cuidadosa e não geraria erros, precisaria garantir que jamais se escrevesse/lesse dados além da área de fato reservada. Um passo inicial pode ser manipular o ponteiro como `char *` ao invés de `int *`, com o código dessa forma:

```
char *ptr = (char *) malloc(sizeof(int));   

ptr[0] = 5;
ptr[1] = 10;

free(ptr);
```

Assim, o resultado da penúltima linha (`ptr[1] = 10;`) geraria atualização na memória apenas no segundo byte (dado que `char` tem 1 byte de tamanho):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ainda assim, é preciso tomar cuidado com o valor que é atribuido. O valor decimal `10` (em hexadecimal, `0a`) requer apenas 1 byte para ser representado, mas qualquer valor decimal acima de `255` (`FF` em hexadecimal) precisaria de mais do que 1 byte e poderia invadir a memória se não for tomado o devido cuidado (por exemplo, uma atualiação no 4 byte como `ptr[3] = 10` é ok, mas como `ptr[3] = 256` não é ok!).

Comment: Muito bom, não tenho paciência de escrever assim com tantos detalhes e ilustrações. Normalmente a resposta de programadores que manjam de C é RTFM =D. +1

Comment: Obrigado! Realmente. Responder RTFM e não responder nada só não são equivalentes porque o segundo não ocupa espaço e ainda assim é mais educado. :)

Answer (score 4):

André,

A função **malloc** localiza espaços na memoria que estão disponíveis. Utilizando da forma citada, apenas o endereço de **ptr[0]** estará "reservado" para seu programa, com isso, seu programa poderá apresentar problemas em sua execução pois:

1. *A memoria que você utilizará após o tamanho da memoria "reservada" poderá pertencer a outra aplicação.*
2. *Os bits que você utilizar a mais, poderão pertencer a sua própria aplicação.*
3. *Utilizar espaços de memorias reservados, causando um crash na sua aplicação.*

Este tipo de comportamento é conhecido como [Buffer Overflow](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transbordamento_de_dados)

Para aumentar o tamanho do espaço reservado com **malloc**, é possivel utilizar a função **realloc**.