# Tipo abstrato de variável

Tags: c++

Tenho essa linha de código:

```
USphereComponent * SphereComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USphereComponent>(TEXT("RootComponent"));
```

Como funciona esse tipo de retorno no meu caso (`USphereComponent`)? A variável vai guardar que tipo tipo de dados (`int` , `char`, ou algum outro valor padrão)? E qual vai ser o tamanho dela?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

Ela vai guardar um ponteiro para uma instância de objeto da classe `USphereComponent`. Se você precisar entender mais sobre ponteiros, sugiro estas outras perguntas aqui do SOPT mesmo:

- [Qual a diferença entre ponteiro e referência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56470/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ponteiro-e-refer%C3%AAncia)
- [Didática simples de Ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26633/did%C3%A1tica-simples-de-ponteiros)

Além da memória ocupada pelo ponteiro, há também o consumo de memória dado pelo tamanho do objeto instanciado em memória, que vai depender do que está declarado na classe (isso é, o que ela contém - essencialmente seus atributos com respectivos tamanhos).

Mesmo se a classe não é de implementação sua, deve ser possível estimar o tamanho dela com base na chamada `sizeof(USphereComponent)`. Mais detalhes sobre o `sizeof` nestas perguntas do SOEN:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552319/c-sizeof-of-a-class-with-functions
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261595/c-sizeof-custom-class-returning-incorrect-value

Outra boa leitura [é esse artigo](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/size_of_class_object.html).

Answer (score 4):

Você poderia ter informado que está mexendo com a *engine* do **Unreal**. Outra coisa, `USphereComponent` não é **abstrata**. Tecnicamente falando, ela é considerada **concreta** porque você pode instanciar objetos deste tipo de dado.

Bem, a declaração da variável `USphereComponent * SphereComponent` já indica o que ela é:

> Um **ponteiro** para um objeto do tipo [`USphereComponent`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/USphereComponent/index.html).

`USphereComponent` é um **tipo de dado** oferecido pela *engine* do Unreal, assim como `char`, `int`, `float` e `double` são **tipos de dados primitivos** oferecidos pela linguagem C/C++.

Na verdade, novos tipos de dados (*structs* e *classes*) da linguagem C/C++ podem ser criados a partir de uma ou mais variáveis dos tipos de dados primitivos (que você já conhece).

Para saber quais variáveis e métodos estão encapsulados dentro de `USphereComponent` você deve consultar a [documentação da API (*Application Programming Interface*) do *Unreal Engine*](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/USphereComponent/index.html). Essa é uma prática bastante comum quando vamos usar uma API que pouco conhecemos: IDE para escrever código-fonte posicionado em um lado da tela, navegador para visualizar a documentação da API do outro.

Se nada disso fez sentido, comece investigando **o que é um ponteiro**, depois **o que é alocação de memória dinâmica**, e por último, **o que são classes**, para se sentir mais a vontade programando em C++ e usando APIs de outras pessoas.