# (Erro de segmentation fault) Faça um programa que receba duas frases distintas e imprima de maneira invertida

Tags: c, array

Pessoal não sei aonde está o erro. Toda vez que eu compilo acusa erro de segmentation fault (core dumped), alguém pode me ajudar? O código está aqui:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int strlen(char *s);
char *strrev(char *s);

int main() {
char frase1[30+1];
char frase2[30+1];

printf("Digite uma frase: ");
gets(frase1);
printf("Digite outra frase: ");
gets(frase2);
printf("Frase 1 = %s\n", strrev(frase1));
printf("Frase 2 = %s\n", strrev(frase2));

return 0;
}

int strlen(char *s) {
int i;
while(s[i]) {
    i++;
}
return i;
}

char *strrev(char *s) {
int i, len;
char aux;
for(i=0,len=strlen(s)-1; i<len; i++, len--) {
    aux = s[i];
    s[i] = s[len];
    s[len] = aux;
}
return s;
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Didática simples de Ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26633/did%c3%a1tica-simples-de-ponteiros)

Comment: Em `strlen`, você não definiu o valor inicial de `i`, portanto ele é lixo de memória

Comment: Outra alternativa seria que o tamanho da frase é muito grande

Comment: Caraca nem tinha percebido , @JeffersonQuesado pela ajuda.

Comment: @PatrickCardoso transformei em resposta para ficar armazenado o histórico correto

Comment: @PatrickCardoso, se a resposta (que nasceu do comentário) resolver seu problema do modo correto, favor marcar como a resposta aceita.

Answer (score 2):

Foi um pequeno descuido.

Em `strlen`, o valor de `i` não está inicializado. O seguinte código corrige:

```
int strlen(char *s) {
  int i = 0;
  while(s[i]) {
    i++;
  }
  return i;
}
```

Como `i` não foi inicializado, ele começa com lixo de memória

Answer (score 0):

Me parece q vc não conhece a biblioteca "string.h", pois esta tentando recriar funções já prontas, como "strlen()" e "strrev()". É mt simples resolver seu problema, basta usar a biblioteca "string.h" e usar as funções.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char frase[31];
    printf("Digite uma frase: ");
    gets(frase);
    printf("Frase invertida = %s\n", strrev(frase));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A sua resposta não foca o erro citado não pergunta. Lembre-se que o autor da pergunta pode estar a tentar recriar as funções em `string.h` para aprender e praticar.

Comment: Conheço sim pow, mas estou recriando essas funções pra praticar, entende?

Comment: @Isac Exatamente.