# Por que não consigo imprimir o que tem dentro da lista?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include<conio.h>  

typedef struct cadastro {
  char nome[30];
  char matricula[30];
  char Disciplinas[30];
  char notas[30];
  struct cadastro *proxno;
} alunos;

int inserir_aluno_inicio(alunos *lista);
alunos *remover_aluno(alunos *lista);
int menu(void);
void opcoes(alunos *lista, int opc);
alunos *liberar();
int inicializar();
void imprimir(alunos *lista);

int main()
{
  int opcao;
  alunos *lista = (alunos *)malloc(sizeof(alunos));

  lista = inicializar();

  do
  {
    opcao = menu();
    opcoes(lista, opcao);
  } while (opcao != 5);

  return 0;
}

int inicializar()
{
  return NULL;
}

int inserir_aluno_inicio(alunos *lista)
{  
  alunos *novo = (alunos *)malloc(sizeof(alunos));

  if (novo == NULL)
  {
    puts("Sem memória");
    return 1;
  }

  printf("Digite o nome do aluno ou da aluna: ");
  scanf(" %s", novo->nome);

  printf("Digite a matricula do aluno ou aluna[5 numeros ou letras]:");
  scanf(" %s", novo->matricula);

  printf("Digite a disciplina do aluno ou aluna: ");
  scanf(" %s", novo->Disciplinas);

  printf("Digite a nota da aluna ou do aluno:");
  scanf(" %s", novo->notas);

  puts("");

  novo->proxno = lista;
  lista = novo;
  return 0;
}  
//  
int menu()
{
  int ale;
  puts(" M E N U___E S C O L A R___V I N G A D O R E S \n");
  puts("=============================\n");
  printf("[ 0 ] INSERIR ALUNO     =\n");
  puts("[ 1 ] REMOVER ALUNO       =\n");
  puts("[ 2 ] IMPRIMIR INFORMACOES DO ALUNO =\n");
  puts("[ 3 ] LIMPAR LISTA DE ALUNOS =\n");
  puts("[ 4 ] SAIR DA LISTA        =\n");
  puts("==============================\n");
  scanf("%d", &ale);
  return ale;
}  

void opcoes(alunos *lista, int opc)
{
  switch (opc)
  {
    case 0:
      inserir_aluno_inicio(lista);
      break;
    case 1:
      break;
    case 2:
      imprimir(lista);
      break;
    case 3:
      break;
    case 4:
      puts("Ate a proxima!");
      break;  
    default:
      puts("Nao existe essa opcao tente novamente!");
  }
}  

void imprimir(alunos *lista)
{
  alunos *aux = lista;
  while (aux != NULL)
  {  
    printf("O nome da aluna(o): %s", aux->nome);
    printf("\n");
    printf("A matricula do aluno(a) e: %s", aux->matricula);
    printf("\n");
    printf("A disciplina da aluna(o) e: %s",aux->Disciplinas);
    printf("\n");
    printf("A nota do aluno (a): %s", aux->notas);
    printf("\n");
    aux = aux->proxno;
  }  
}
```

O  QUE JÁ TENTEI FAZER: O que já tentei foi na alocar a memória um novo elemento ou seja novo cadastro, mas quando chamo função imprimir ele mostra numero e caracteres aleatórios. Mesmo quando faço para a lista principal receber a nova alocação, que foi o que tentei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Vejamos...

Tenha em mente o seguinte:

- Um **ponteiro é uma variável que guarda um endereço** ao invés de um valor de tipo conhecido. Se acessado, o endereço guardado pode conter outro endereço ou um valor de tipo conhecido;
- **Toda variável tem um endereço próprio**. Assim, uma variável "tradicional" tem um endereço próprio e uma variável ponteiro também. Trabalhemos com igualdade - sempre!
- **O nome de uma variável nada mais é que um mnemônico para o endereço dela**. Ou seja, um sinônimo.

### Olhando o problema de perto

Considere o seguinte código de representação genérica:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct meu { int valor; struct minha *prox; } tipo;

void incluir(tipo *lista){

    tipo *temp = (tipo *) malloc(...);

    temp->valor = 5;

    temp->prox = lista;
    lista = temp;

}

void imprimir(tipo *lista){

    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%d ", lista->valor);
        temp = temp->prox;
    }

}

int main(){

    tipo *lista = NULL;

    incluir(lista);
    imprimir(lista);

    return(0);
}
```

Agora vamos narrar os eventos que se sucedem:

- cria-se um ponteiro chamado `lista` de um dado `tipo`;
- passa o endereço **apontado** pelo ponteiro `lista` para a função de inclusão;
- na função de inclusão, cria-se um ponteiro temporário para uma nova entrada de dados;
- coloca-se no `prox` da nova entrada o endereço apontado pelo ponteiro `lista`;
- faz-se o ponteiro `lista` apontar para o endereço da nova entrada;
- faz-se a chamada da função de impressão para imprimir o conteúdo da lista;
- falha miseravelmente e se indaga sobre o ofício da mãe de Dennis Ritchie;

Para que salvemos a honra da pobre senhora mãe deste gênio da computação, devemos mitigar o problema. Vamos que vamos!

### Analise de caso

Considere que o endereço do ponteiro `lista` seja `0x02`. Preste atenção: é o endereço dele e não do conteúdo dele; que ele aponta! No caso, `lista` aponta para `NULL`. temos então algo do tipo `0x02 -> NULL` na memória.

Considere a tabela de memória para auxiliar na explicação:

```
+===================================+
|         Tabela de Memória         |
+----------+------------------------+
| Endereço | Valor                  |
+===================================+
|   0x01   | 5                      |
+----------+------------------------+
|   0x02   | NULL                   |
+----------+------------------------+
|   0x03   | 0x30                   |
+----------+------------------------+
|   0x04   | livro k&r download pdf |
+----------+------------------------+
|   0x05   | NULL                   |
+----------+------------------------+
|   0x06   | ab..$5%ab asd/         |
+----------+------------------------+
+         ...                       +
```

Ao passar `lista` como argumento de `incluir()`, passamos o endereço que ele aponta. Passamos `NULL`. Lembre-se que uma variável sempre passa seu valor em qualquer instância normal e não seu endereço.

Dentro da função `incluir()`, esperamos que `lista` esteja no endereço `0x02` com o valor `NULL`. OK...

*HÁ! Pegadinha do malandro!*

Isso está completamente errado! O que temos em `lista` (em `incluir()`) é o *valor a qual aponta o ponteiro* e *não o endereço do ponteiro*. A variável `lista` (em `incluir()`) é na verdade outra variável em outro endereço (digamos `0x05`). Só que o valor a que aponta `lista` em `incluir()` é o mesmo de `lista` em `main()`.

A conseqüência direta disso é que **a referência se perde**. Isso explica o fato de falharmos em imprimir.

### Solução

Para lidar com este problema, precisamos do valor apontado por `lista` bem como do endereço de `lista` em si. Isso é facilmente feito passando `&lista` para as funções ao invés de `lista`. Desta forma, nossa memória ficaria assim:

```
+===================================+
|         Tabela de Memória         |
+----------+------------------------+
| Endereço | Valor                  |
+===================================+
|   0x01   | 5                      |
+----------+------------------------+
|   0x02   | NULL                   |
+----------+------------------------+
|   0x03   | 0x30                   |
+----------+------------------------+
|   0x04   | livro k&r download pdf |
+----------+------------------------+
|   0x05   | 0x02                   |
+----------+------------------------+
|   0x06   | ab..$5%ab asd/         |
+----------+------------------------+
+         ...                       +
```

Nossas funções ficariam assim:

```
void incluir(tipo **lista){ ...

void imprimir(tipo **lista){ ...
```

As chamadas de funções ficariam como segue:

```
incluir( &lista );
imprimir( &lista );
```

**Concluindo**: lista dentro de `incluir()` vai apontar para o endereço de `lista` dentro de `main()` que por sua vez vai apontar para o tipo conhecido. Assim, você consegue também rastrear `lista` e não só o conteúdo para qual aponta.

### Arrumando o programa

O ideal é que você mesmo tente arrumar. Se não conseguir, dê uma olhada nesta versão funcional do mesmo.

O código abaixo contém algumas modificações visuais que fiz para conseguir entender melhor seu programa. Isso inclui a forma como as informações são mostradas. Modifique a seu bel-prazer.

**Bibliotecas:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

**Estruturas**:

```
typedef struct cadastro {

    char nome[30];
    char matricula[30];
    char Disciplinas[30];
    char notas[30];

    struct cadastro *proxno;

} alunos;
```

**Declarações de funções:**

```
int inserir_aluno_inicio(alunos **lista);
int menu(void);

void opcoes(alunos **lista, int opc);
void imprimir(alunos **lista);

alunos *remover_aluno(alunos **lista);
alunos *liberar();
alunos *inicializar();
```

**Função** `main()`**:**

```
int main() {

    int opcao;
    alunos *lista = (alunos *)malloc(sizeof(alunos));

    lista = inicializar();

    do {
        opcao = menu();
        opcoes(&lista, opcao);
    } while (opcao < 4);

    return 0;

}
```

**Função** `inicializar()`**:**

```
alunos *inicializar() { return NULL; }
```

**Função** `menu()`**:**

```
int menu() {

    int ale;

    puts("\n  M E N U   E S C O L A R   V I N G A D O R E S \n");
    puts(" ===============================================\n");
    puts(" =  [ 0 ]  INSERIR ALUNO                       =\n");
    puts(" =  [ 1 ]  REMOVER ALUNO                       =\n");
    puts(" =  [ 2 ]  IMPRIMIR INFORMACOES DO ALUNO       =\n");
    puts(" =  [ 3 ]  LIMPAR LISTA DE ALUNOS              =\n");
    puts(" =  [ 4 ]  SAIR DA LISTA                       =\n");
    puts(" ===============================================\n");
    printf(" COMANDO > ");

    scanf("%d", &ale);

    return ale;

}
```

**Função** `inserir_aluno_inicio()`**:**

```
int inserir_aluno_inicio(alunos **lista) {  

    alunos *novo = (alunos *) malloc( sizeof( alunos ) );

    if (novo == NULL)
    {
        puts(" Sem memória!");

        return 1;
    }


    printf("\n Digite o nome do aluno ou da aluna: ");
    scanf(" %s", novo->nome);

    printf(" Digite a matricula do aluno ou aluna [5 numeros ou letras]: ");
    scanf(" %s", novo->matricula);

    printf(" Digite a disciplina do aluno ou aluna: ");
    scanf(" %s", novo->Disciplinas);

    printf(" Digite a nota da aluna ou do aluno: ");
    scanf(" %s", novo->notas);

    puts("");


    novo->proxno = *lista;
    *lista = novo;


    return 0;

}
```

**Função** `opcoes()`**:**

```
void opcoes(alunos **lista, int opc) {

    switch (opc) {

        case 0:
            inserir_aluno_inicio(lista);
            break;

        case 1:
            break;

        case 2:
            imprimir(lista);
            break;

        case 3:
            break;

        case 4:
            puts("\n Ate a proxima!\n");
            break;  

        default:
            puts(" Nao existe essa opcao tente novamente!");

    }

}
```

**Função** `imprimir()`**:**

```
void imprimir(alunos **lista) {

    alunos *aux = *lista;

    while (aux != NULL){

        printf("\n\tO nome da aluna(o): %s\n", aux->nome);
        printf("\tA matricula do aluno(a) e: %s\n", aux->matricula);
        printf("\tA disciplina da aluna(o) e: %s\n",aux->Disciplinas);
        printf("\tA nota do aluno (a): %s\n", aux->notas);

        aux = aux->proxno;

    }

}
```

O código também se encontra no [GitHub](https://github.com/jfcandidofilho/stackoverflow/tree/master/371358). Se achar mais fácil, olhe ele inteiro num único arquivo por lá.

Se mesmo assim você não entendeu, procure outra fonte. Recomendo essa resposta do [Lucas Virgili](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/26642/839).

Comment: Obrigado. Você arrasou na resposta.

Comment: Deu certo, viu! Vou postar o código solucionado ou deixo o erro acima e o seu comentário de resolução mesmo?

Comment: A plataforma funciona da seguinte forma: você posta uma pergunta e uma ou mais pessoas respondem. A melhor resposta dentre as que solucionam o problema, você marca como correta e dá um positivo: as ações servem para agradecer quem te ajudou. Uma resposta correta também serve para ajudar outros com problemas semelhantes. Nos casos em que ninguém responde ou soluciona o problema, se encontrares a solução podes escrever uma resposta e marcar a sua própria resposta como correta. A pergunta só é editada para ser melhorada, nunca para responder. Se minha resposta ajudou, pode marcar como correta. :)